# ObjectAL/OpenAL for iOS - stop/pause/mute sound at runtime?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, audio

Here is the ObjectAL/OpenAL iOS  documentation:

http://kstenerud.github.io/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/documentation/index.html#use_objectal_sec

How in the world can you simply stop/pause/mute a particular sound (not all sounds) at runtime?

I've tried using OALSimpleAudio, OpenAL Objects and OALAudioTrack with no luck.

I'm using cocos2d v3.

Comment: ALSource is what you are looking for. And with ALChannelSource you can stop/pause/pitch/etc all sound sources playing in the same channel.

Comment: Ok. Cool thanks! Any samples around?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the examples provided in: [ObjectAL demos](https://github.com/kstenerud/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/tree/master/ObjectALDemo/OALDemo%20%28iOS%29/Demos), for instance the SingleSourceDemo.

On of them is for the ALSource that @LearnCocos2D suggested in his comment. I will try to explain it here. 
First, you should have the audio engine - let's say it is OALSimpleAudio. Moreover, let's assume you don't want to use it for playing effects - they will be managed by separate ALSources:

```
    ALSource* effectSource;
    ALBuffer* effectBuffer; //this is for the effect buffer

    //don't reserve source for OALSimpleAudio 
    [OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance].reservedSources = 0;

    //create the source for the effect.
    source = [ALSource source]; 

    //buffer the source file. 
    buffer = [[OpenALManager sharedInstance] bufferFromFile:@"audiofile.caf"];
```

Now you can use following methods to play/pause/pitch:

```
    [source play:buffer loop:YES]; //play sound from buffer and loop
    [source stop]; //stop 
    [source rewind]; //rewind sound to the beggining 
    [source fadeTo:0.0f duration:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(onFadeComplete:)]; //fade effect from source
    [source pitchTo:0.0f duration:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(onFadeComplete:)]; //pitch effect from source
```

etc. Hope this will be helpful.